# Can this be written better? Call functions depending on previous result

Tags: c#

I have the following code written in c# that checks various tests, and if any fails the result is false and don't want the other checks to be executed.

The way I have coded seems "ugly", and I wondered if there was a more elegant solution that I am missing due to brain fade this morning.

```
//check the rules
bool isValid = CheckPhoneFormat();
if (isValid)
{
    isValid = CheckDoNotCall();
}

if (isValid)
{
    isValid = CheckStatusActive();
}

if (isValid)
{
    isValid = CheckOCV();
}

if (isValid)
{
    isValid = CheckCard();
}

customer.IsValid = isValid;
```

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Imo, your approach is absolutely fine since it's readable, efficient, easy to debug, to test and to maintain. Don't measure code quality in lines or letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
bool isValid = CheckPhoneFormat() && CheckDoNotCall()
               && CheckStatusActive() && CheckOCV() && CheckCard();
customer.IsValid = isValid;
```

The `&&` operator evaluates the second operand only if the first one is `true`.

**EDIT**
Since all the methods you call are parameterless, consider to convert them to get-only properties (and rename). It may help with debugging.

```
bool isValid = IsValidPhoneFormat && IsValidDoNotCall
               && IsValidStatusActive && IsValidOCV && IsValidCard;
customer.IsValid = isValid;
```

Comment: I'd prefer OP's approach. It's better to debug.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree, the debugging may be a problem in this case. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 9):

This adds the overhead for creating a state machine:

```
static Enumerable<Func<bool>() GetRules()
{

    yield return CheckPhoneFormat();
    yield return CheckDoNotCall();
    yield return CheckStatusActive();
    yield return CheckOCV();
    yield return CheckCard();
}

bool oneValid = GetRules().Any(b => b);
bool allValid = GetRules().All(b => b);
```

More efficient if you will:

```
static IEnumerable<Func<bool>> arr = new Func<bool>[]
{
    () => CheckPhoneFormat(),
    () => CheckDoNotCall(),
    () => CheckStatusActive(),
    () => CheckOCV(),
    () => CheckCard();
};

bool oneValid = arr.Any(b => b);
bool allValid = arr.All(b => b);
```

Comment: I would not have thought of using `yield` like that. Very clever!

Comment: Love the cleverness, but think I will go for the short circuit evaluation as the more simple solution

Comment: @jazza1000: yeah, you add some overhead by creating a state machine. I updated my answer.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, Dmitry: thanks! glad I'm not alone to like this approach :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `&&` which will short circuit if a check fails:

```
customer.IsValid = CheckPhoneFormat() && CheckDoNotCall() && CheckStatusActive() ...;
```

Note you don't even need an `if`, you can assign straight to the boolean.

Comment: I don't like this since it's even worse than OP's approach. It's difficult to read if you have to scroll and it's also difficult to debug if you don't store the return values.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Normally I would agree on the debug difficulty, but since he could set breakpoints in each function, I would say its just as simple. As far as readability, you can put each condition on a new line. That said, I see where you are coming from.

Comment: Yes, and that makes it more difficult. You're saving some letters but you're losing  testability. You have to know which methods you have to inspect instead of setting quick break-points. By using multiple lines it's more readable but it  also becomes increasingly similar to OP's approach that is also easier to maintain (f.e. if you want to log that `CheckDoNotCall` returned `true` without modifying the method). By the way, OP's approach is also short circuiting.